# How to Cancel Paypal Subscription?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, subscription, paypal-subscriptions

I finally figured out how to implement PayPal Recurring Billing using this tutorial. http://railscasts.com/episodes/289-paypal-recurring-billing

Everything works, But how does one cancel the subscription....

**Below is all of the code I've written, and I've also added some comments/questions**

**ERROR**

```
app/controllers/subscriptions_controller.rb:27:in `show'

Couldn't find Subscription with id=cancel_account
```

Please help new to rails. :)

**CONTROLLER**

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
    @subscription = plan.subscriptions.build
    @subscription.user_id = current_user.id
    if params[:PayerID]
      @subscription.paypal_customer_token = params[:PayerID]
      @subscription.paypal_payment_token = params[:token]
      @subscription.email = @subscription.paypal.checkout_details.email
    end
  end

  def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new(params[:subscription])
    if @subscription.save_with_payment
      redirect_to @subscription, :notice => "Thank you for subscribing!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @subscription = current_user.subscription
    @previous_plan = @subscription.plan

    if @subscription.cancel_recurring
      flash[:success] = 'Subscription Canceled.'
    end
    redirect_to some_path
  end

  def paypal_checkout
    plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
    subscription = plan.subscriptions.build
    redirect_to subscription.paypal.checkout_url(
      return_url: new_subscription_url(:plan_id => plan.id),
      cancel_url: root_url
    )
  end

end
```

**MODELS**

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :paypal_customer_token, :paypal_recurring_profile_token, 
                  :plan_id, :user_id, :email, :paypal_payment_token

  attr_accessor :paypal_payment_token

  belongs_to :plan
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :plan_id
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_presence_of :user_id

  def save_with_payment
    if valid?
      if paypal_payment_token.present?
       save_with_paypal_payment
    end
  end

  def paypal
    PaypalPayment.new(self)
  end

  def save_with_paypal_payment
    response = paypal.make_recurring
    self.paypal_recurring_profile_token = response.profile_id
    save!
  end

  def payment_provided?
    paypal_payment_token.present?
  end

end

class PaypalPayment
  def initialize(subscription)
    @subscription = subscription
  end

  def checkout_details
    process :checkout_details
  end

  def checkout_url(options)
    process(:checkout, options).checkout_url
  end

  def make_recurring
    process :request_payment
    process :create_recurring_profile, period: :monthly, frequency: 1, 
    start_at: Time.zone.now + 1.month
  end

  def cancel_recurring
    response = ppr.cancel_subscription(at_date_end: true) #Needs a end period field in
    self.current_date_end_at = Time.at(response.current_date_end)
    self.plan_id = plan.id
    self.status = "canceled"
    return self.save
  end

private

  def process(action, options = {})
    options = options.reverse_merge(
      token: @subscription.paypal_payment_token,
      payer_id: @subscription.paypal_customer_token,
      description: @subscription.plan.name,
      amount: @subscription.plan.price.to_i,
      currency: "USD"
    )
    response = PayPal::Recurring.new(options).send(action)
    raise response.errors.inspect if response.errors.present?
    response
  end
end
```

**VIEWS**

```
<%= form_for @subscription do |f| %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :plan_id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :paypal_customer_token %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :paypal_payment_token %>

  <% unless @subscription.payment_provided? %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= radio_button_tag :pay_with, :paypal %>
    <%= label_tag :pay_with_paypal do %>
      <%= image_tag "paypal.png" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <% end %>


*** WHAT WOULD BE THE LINK TO CANCEL THE SUBSCRIPTION ***

    <%= link_to image_tag("https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif"),
    paypal_checkout_path(plan_id: @subscription.plan_id) %>

    <%= link_to "Cancel Subscription", cancel_account_subscriptions_path(plan_id: 
    @subscription.plan_id) %>



  <div id="billing_fields">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

    </div>
    <% if @subscription.payment_provided? %>
      Payment has been provided. Click "Subscribe" to complete the subscription.
    <% end %>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Subscribe" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**ROUTES**

```
App::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :subscriptions do
    collection do
      delete :cancel_account
    end
  end

  get 'paypal/checkout', to: 'subscriptions#paypal_checkout'

end
```

Answer (score 3):

To destroy a users paypal subscription you should create a destroy action in your subscription model.

Subscription_controller.rb

```
  def destroy
    @subscription = current_user.subscription
    @previous_plan = @subscription.plan

    if @subscription.cancel_recurring
      flash[:success] = 'Subscription Canceled.'
    end
    redirect_to some_path
  end
```

In your model get the current user and cancel their subscription. If the user is subscribed monthly but canceled within 2days out of the 30 days, their account subscription should be valid until the at_end_date period(just a heads up).

```
  def cancel_recurring
    response = ppr.cancel_subscription(at_date_end: true) #Needs a end period field in
    self.current_date_end_at = Time.at(response.current_date_end)
    self.plan_id = plan.id
    self.status = "canceled"
    return self.save
  end
```

Routes.rb

```
resources :subscriptions do
 collection do
   delete :cancel_account
 end
end
```

In your view you would iterate through the plans like so

```
<% @plans.each do |plan| %>
  <%= link_to "Cancel Account", cancel_account_subscriptions_path(@subscription, plan_id: plan.id), method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How would i call this from the VIEW....I have tried using <%= link_to "Cancel Subscription", cancel_account_subscriptions_path(plan_id: @subscription.plan_id) %>, but get an error. I have updated the code above

Comment: I get this error The action 'cancel_account' could not be found for SubscriptionsController....

Comment: Try different iterations such as @subscription.plans or check the logs to see what the error is specifically.

Comment: @SurgePedroza did you find a fix to the error? I tried to fix it but couldn't also. Let me know if you had any success.

Comment: @xps15z yea if you post a question i will try to answer it based on my answer. but to be honest i ended up using Strive vs Paypal. Their Documentation was a lot easier to follow

Comment: @SurgePedroza ok the error was just for `Couldn't find Subscription with id=cancel_account`. I will post a question for it then.